# Cocoapods, Library not loaded

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I get this error message :

[Thread 1: signal SIGABRT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHPo4.png)

```
dyld[1057]: Library not loaded:
 @rpath/AlgoliaSearchClient.framework/AlgoliaSearchClient Referenced from: <EFE10BCF-D1E4-32F9-9D3B-BC496485BF96>
 /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B7356B54-300C-462B-8D92-61C64A9342F8/Flash.app/Flash
 Reason: tried:
 '/usr/lib/swift/AlgoliaSearchClient.framework/AlgoliaSearchClient' (no
 such file, not in dyld cache),
 '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/AlgoliaSearchClient.framework/AlgoliaSearchClient'
 (no such file),
 '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B7356B54-300C-462B-8D92-61C64A9342F8/Flash.app/Frameworks/AlgoliaSearchClient.framework/AlgoliaSearchClient'
 (no such file),
 '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B7356B54-300C-462B-8D92-61C64A9342F8/Flash.app/Frameworks/AlgoliaSearchClient.framework/AlgoliaSearchClient'
 (no such file),
 '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B7356B54-300C-462B-8D92-61C64A9342F8/Flash.app/Frameworks/AlgoliaSearchClient.framework/AlgoliaSearchClient'
 (no such file),
 '/usr/lib/swift/AlgoliaSearchClient.framework/AlgoliaSearchClient' (no
 such file, not in dyld cache),
 '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/AlgoliaSearchClient.framework/AlgoliaSearchClient'
 (no such file),
 '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B7356B54-300C-462B-8D92-61C64A9342F8/Flash.app/Frameworks/AlgoliaSearchClient.framework/AlgoliaSearchClient'
 (no such file),
 '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B7356B54-300C-462B-8D92-61C64A9342F8/Flash.app/Frameworks/AlgoliaSearchClient.framework/AlgoliaSearchClient'
 (no such file),
 '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B7356B54-300C-462B-8D92-61C64A9342F8/Flash.app/Frameworks/AlgoliaSearchClient.framework/AlgoliaSearchClient'
 (no such file),
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/AlgoliaSearchClient.framework/AlgoliaSearchClient'
 (no such file, not in dyld cache) (lldb) ’
```

The error is not from algolia but from cocoap or xcode because Algolia is only the first framework in the install list and when I remove it from podfile I get the same error with the second framework.

I tried many thing, clean build folder, delete derived data, restart mac, uninstall and reinstall all pod files.

I hope someone can help me solve this problem!

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. The pictures can't be searched or referenced (and they are harder to post). Please edit your question and replace the pictures with the actual text, copied and pasted into your question.

Answer (score -1):

When installing cocoapods, you'll need to close the xcodeproj and open the `.xcworkspace` generated when you run `pod install`.

Cocoapods also warns you of this:

> [!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `PodSample.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
> Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.

Comment: Yes, I'm already launching the "xcworkspace" project